# url rewrite domain depending on url param

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a joomla website in french and german.
I can switch from one to the other with url param lang=fr or lang=de

I would like to switch the domain name depending on the url param.

```
if lang=fr 
    rewrite www.frenchdomainname.ch/old_params
if lang=de 
    rewrite www.germandomainname.ch/old_params
```

Is there a way to do it from with htaccess redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !frenchdomainname\.ch [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)lang=fr&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.frenchdomainname.ch/$1?%1%2 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !germandomainname\.ch [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)lang=de&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.germandomainname.ch/$1?%1%2 [L,R]
```